# Django Paypal IPN Signal for Recurring payment

Tags: django-paypal

Our website is  using Django Paypal plugin for upfront payment.

We were using paypal for registration and one time fee. This worked fine. Now we have gone ahead and implemented  subscription model. 
All works well but recurring payment signal fails to come through.

With IPN URL registered the payment signals comes through . But the recurring signals fail.

http://www.company.com/notify/

Paypal IPN history page shows Retrying for recurring payment and sent for successful payments.
The log files do not show any error and apache access.log shows

"POST //notify/ HTTP/1.0" 200 4 "-" "-" - for payment_was_successful signal

"POST //notify/ HTTP/1.0" 500 35434 "-" "-"  for recurring payment

Did post a question to PAYPAL MTS but failed to get hear any userful feedback
Did try creating a form and posting the content to the same URL and this too worked.

IPN method in paypal->ipn->views returns OKAY.Is this the method called for subscription too?

Eagerly looking for some help or feedback...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue partly by downloading the latest code from [github- dcramer](https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal). Updated one has signal handling for subscription.